# No such file or directory error for npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

I think I have installed npm.. But when I try to type `npm -v`  ,it shows

```
  -bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

How to fix that.. `node -v` works fine... The terminal shows

```
v0.12.4
```

Can anyone help me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed that problem by reinstall node and npm. For mac user, try to type

```
sudo curl -L npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Hope it works.